# Unable to connect to my GAE account through appcfg

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, appcfg

I was surprized not to be able to connect to my account through appcfg my password was right, butthe app ansered it's not.

When I change the google setting : https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps to make `Access for less secure apps` **enabled**, it worked.

Is there something I'm missing or must i have this security hole open to be able to use appcfg?

Please notice I'm using eclipse to publish my apps, and the eclipse plugin connects with even if the accont security is safe, but calling appcfg from the command line for roll back was the operation that failed...

I thought eclipse uses the command line to upload my app? I'm obviously wrong.

So the question is: is there something I have to do to be able to have `Access for less secure apps` **disabled** and use appcfg ?

Comment: I've got same problem. Did you solve it?

Comment: Hi @timmacp , I think the --oauth2 solved it (or google did it on their side)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround is to use an [OAuth2](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp)  token instead of using password based authentication.It is more convenient.

just add the option  --oauth2 before the update, you get a key which you paste  in for appcfg

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to try uploading your GAE app from the command line by:

- Open CMD
- Going to the GAE \ BIN directory
- Enter the following command:

appcfg.exe update PATH_YOUR_APP_WAR

After that you will be required to enter your GAE email address and password, that's it

Comment: ??? I'm not asking how to do, I'm saying it doesn't work: after entering the email and pass, the login is rejected.